# When does P Channel mosfet have 12v on drain as output?

Tags: mosfet

Ok, so I have an engine control module for an RTV, and I know that based on a neutral safety switch, it will only allow you to start the engine if it is on park or neutral. So, basically what I have found out is that when DRAIN is 12v, the starter is allowed to crank based on this output, however I noticed that I have only got 12v on DRAIN once while trying to change different gears. Meaning that it is an intermittent issue. I have checked that GATE has about 12v and SOURCE has 12v at all times when changing gears to park or drive, but when I saw that DRAIN had 12v, I did not check what SOURCE and GATE have. So, my question is, how does DRAIN turn into 12v? Is it when GATE becomes ground, if so the problem is going to be whatever drives the GATE? I am still trying to figure out if this is a computer fault or not. The mosfet part number is J530, and I do see another IC chip, I do not know if it drives the gate or not, but here is the part number, MH3292F16. NOTE: J2 and AB on schematic, I am not sure exactly what these transistors are, no part number either.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFsjdv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Please use the built-in schematic editor to draw a schematic of the circuit in question.

Comment: I must say, I am not that good at making schematics, but I tried.

Comment: I have not checked which pin will get ground if I change to park or drive, I think I should check that. I only checked for voltage change, I do not know if neutral or park mode will send ground or voltage signal.

Comment: I could be having a mechanical issue, as I do not see any voltage or ground signal changes when changing to park or drive.